# Problem summing a total in XSLT Template

Tags: xml, xslt

I am having a problem trying to simply sum some values using XSLT. I a template online and have modified it for my needs. ([link text](http://blog.davidkaspar.com/archives/2003/10/xslt-sum-of-products-from-multiple-nodes.php))

No matter how I try, I cannot get the template to sum the numbers. I either end up with a total of "0" or a concatenation of the numbers I want summed. If someone could take a look and point out where I am going wrong, I would greatly appreciated it.

Thanks

** TEMPLATE **

```
print("<xsl:template match="Parts">
    <root>
        <xsl:variable name="tmpTotal">
            <total_amount>
                <xsl:for-each select="Part">
                    <item>
                        <xsl:value-of select="Duration"/>
                    </item>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </total_amount>
        </xsl:variable>
        <total>
            <xsl:variable name="myTotal" select="number(msxsl:node-set($tmpTotal))" /> <!--Shows up as 0-->
            <xsl:value-of select="sum(msxsl:node-set($myTotal)/total_amount/item)" />
            <!--<xsl:variable name="myTotal" select="msxsl:node-set($tmpTotal)" />--> <!-- Shows up as concatenation-->
            <!--<xsl:value-of select="msxsl:node-set($myTotal)" />--> 
        </total>
    </root>
</xsl:template>");
```

** XML **

```
print("<Parts>
<Part>
  <PartNum>0000-A123</PartNum> 
  <Rate>0</Rate> 
  <Rate0Decimal>0</Rate0Decimal> 
  <ProductRemovedNumber>...</ProductRemovedNumber> 
  <Qty>2</Qty> 
  <Resolution>False</Resolution> 
  <ReturnFA>False</ReturnFA> 
  <SerialNumber /> 
  <TickProblemCD>15</TickProblemCD> 
  <TicketNum>075020009000048</TicketNum> 
  <Total>0</Total> 
  <Total0Decimal>0</Total0Decimal> 
  <TotalDisplay>0</TotalDisplay> 
  <UserNumber>009</UserNumber> 
  </Part>
<Part>
  <Duration>2</Duration>
  <Total>0</Total> 
  <PartCost>0.00</PartCost> 
  <PartCost0Decimal>0</PartCost0Decimal> 
  <PerformedBy>TEST</PerformedBy> 
  <WorkDoneCode /> 
  <WorkDoneDesc /> 
  <ZoneBasedTravel>False</ZoneBasedTravel> 
  <PartNum>Travel</PartNum> 
  <PartDescr>---</PartDescr> 
  <Qty>2</Qty> 
  </Part>
<Part>
  <Duration>4</Duration> 
  <DurationRequired>True</DurationRequired> 
  <EndTime>12/4/2008 2:24 PM</EndTime> 
  <EndTimeOnly>12/4/2008</EndTimeOnly> 
  <FamilyName>NON-COMPLAINT</FamilyName> 
  <FOC>False</FOC> 
  <InvTxnGenerated /> 
  <LastUpdatedDate>12/4/2008 2:24 PM</LastUpdatedDate> 
  <Rate>0</Rate> 
  <Rate0Decimal>0</Rate0Decimal> 
  <RateType>Install</RateType> 
  <Total>0</Total> 
  <PartCost>0.00</PartCost> 
  <PartCost0Decimal>0</PartCost0Decimal> 
  <PerformedBy>TEST</PerformedBy> 
  <WorkDoneCode>17000</WorkDoneCode> 
  <WorkDoneDesc>De-Installation / Instrument Move</WorkDoneDesc> 
  <ZoneBasedTravel>False</ZoneBasedTravel> 
  <PartNum>Labor</PartNum> 
  <PartDescr>Install</PartDescr> 
  <Qty>4</Qty> 
  </Part>
<Part>
  <Duration>1</Duration> 
  <DurationRequired>True</DurationRequired> 
  <EndTime>12/4/2008 2:24 PM</EndTime> 
  <EndTimeOnly>12/4/2008</EndTimeOnly> 
  <FamilyName>NON-COMPLAINT</FamilyName> 
  <FOC>False</FOC> 
  <InvTxnGenerated /> 
  <LastUpdatedDate>12/4/2008 2:24 PM</LastUpdatedDate> 
  <Rate>0</Rate> 
  <Rate0Decimal>0</Rate0Decimal> 
  <RateType>TSB/ISA</RateType> 
  <Total>0</Total> 
  <PartCost>0.00</PartCost> 
  <PartCost0Decimal>0</PartCost0Decimal> 
  <PerformedBy>TEST</PerformedBy> 
  <WorkDoneCode>13000</WorkDoneCode> 
  <WorkDoneDesc>TSB / ISA - Installed</WorkDoneDesc> 
  <ZoneBasedTravel>False</ZoneBasedTravel> 
  <PartNum>Labor</PartNum> 
  <PartDescr>TSB/ISA</PartDescr> 
  <Qty>1</Qty> 
  </Part>
  </Parts>");
```

Answer (score 4):

You do not explain exactly which are the values to be summed.

**Judging from the presented XSLT code, it appears that you want the sum of the values of all "Duration" elements**. This can be obtained using the following simple XPath expression:

**`sum(/*/*/Duration)`**

**Below is the complete XSLT transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:value-of select="sum(/*/*/Duration)"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<Parts>
    <Part>
        <PartNum>0000-A123</PartNum>
        <Rate>0</Rate>
        <Rate0Decimal>0</Rate0Decimal>
        <ProductRemovedNumber>...</ProductRemovedNumber>
        <Qty>2</Qty>
        <Resolution>False</Resolution>
        <ReturnFA>False</ReturnFA>
        <SerialNumber />
        <TickProblemCD>15</TickProblemCD>
        <TicketNum>075020009000048</TicketNum>
        <Total>0</Total>
        <Total0Decimal>0</Total0Decimal>
        <TotalDisplay>0</TotalDisplay>
        <UserNumber>009</UserNumber>
    </Part>
    <Part>
        <Duration>2</Duration>
        <Total>0</Total>
        <PartCost>0.00</PartCost>
        <PartCost0Decimal>0</PartCost0Decimal>
        <PerformedBy>TEST</PerformedBy>
        <WorkDoneCode />
        <WorkDoneDesc />
        <ZoneBasedTravel>False</ZoneBasedTravel>
        <PartNum>Travel</PartNum>
        <PartDescr>---</PartDescr>
        <Qty>2</Qty>
    </Part>
    <Part>
        <Duration>4</Duration>
        <DurationRequired>True</DurationRequired>
        <EndTime>12/4/2008 2:24 PM</EndTime>
        <EndTimeOnly>12/4/2008</EndTimeOnly>
        <FamilyName>NON-COMPLAINT</FamilyName>
        <FOC>False</FOC>
        <InvTxnGenerated />
        <LastUpdatedDate>12/4/2008 2:24 PM</LastUpdatedDate>
        <Rate>0</Rate>
        <Rate0Decimal>0</Rate0Decimal>
        <RateType>Install</RateType>
        <Total>0</Total>
        <PartCost>0.00</PartCost>
        <PartCost0Decimal>0</PartCost0Decimal>
        <PerformedBy>TEST</PerformedBy>
        <WorkDoneCode>17000</WorkDoneCode>
        <WorkDoneDesc>De-Installation / Instrument Move</WorkDoneDesc>
        <ZoneBasedTravel>False</ZoneBasedTravel>
        <PartNum>Labor</PartNum>
        <PartDescr>Install</PartDescr>
        <Qty>4</Qty>
    </Part>
    <Part>
        <Duration>1</Duration>
        <DurationRequired>True</DurationRequired>
        <EndTime>12/4/2008 2:24 PM</EndTime>
        <EndTimeOnly>12/4/2008</EndTimeOnly>
        <FamilyName>NON-COMPLAINT</FamilyName>
        <FOC>False</FOC>
        <InvTxnGenerated />
        <LastUpdatedDate>12/4/2008 2:24 PM</LastUpdatedDate>
        <Rate>0</Rate>
        <Rate0Decimal>0</Rate0Decimal>
        <RateType>TSB/ISA</RateType>
        <Total>0</Total>
        <PartCost>0.00</PartCost>
        <PartCost0Decimal>0</PartCost0Decimal>
        <PerformedBy>TEST</PerformedBy>
        <WorkDoneCode>13000</WorkDoneCode>
        <WorkDoneDesc>TSB / ISA - Installed</WorkDoneDesc>
        <ZoneBasedTravel>False</ZoneBasedTravel>
        <PartNum>Labor</PartNum>
        <PartDescr>TSB/ISA</PartDescr>
        <Qty>1</Qty>
    </Part>
</Parts>
```

**The wanted result is produced**:

***7***

**Edit**: In a comment the OP explained that he is looking to `sum` the `Duration` of all `part`-s whose `PartNumber` is equal to "Labor".

**The following XPath expression produces this sum**:

**`sum(/*/*[PartNum='Labor']/Duration)`**

Comment: +1, and should be be accepted answered. i was specifically looking for how to perform totals in xsl. But it looks like Dave closed his account.